# Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 6. Packet size=26

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I use Lumen v7.0 and MySQL v8.0.20 and Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

I have a defined stored procedure in SQL and when I call it I get the following error:

> Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 6. Packet size=26

Here is the connection driver config:

```
'mysql' => [
                'read' => [
                    'host' => [
                        env('DB_HOST')
                    ],
                ],
                'write' => [
                    'host' => [
                        env('DB_HOST'),
                    ],
                ],
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
                'strict' => env('DB_STRICT_MODE', true),
                'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', null),
            ],
```

And here is my code:

```
function storedProcedureBalanceInMerchant($userId, $businessId)
    {
        try {
            $stmt = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo()->prepare("CALL lending_ewallets_balance_in_merchant(?,?);");
            $stmt->execute([$userId, $businessId]);
            $pdoDataResults = [];
            do {
                $rowSet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                array_push($pdoDataResults, $rowSet);
            } while ($stmt->nextRowset());

            return loanBnpl($pdoDataResults);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            dd($exception->getMessage());
            return ['loan' => collect([]), 'bnpl' => collect([])];
        }
    }
```

Noted that, when I call that stored procedure directly in MySQL like `mysql> CALL lending_ewallets_balance_in_merchant(87,165);` it returns the expected result without error.

How can I fix the issue?

---

Also, here is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`administrator`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `lending_ewallets_balance_in_merchant`(IN `user_id_param` BIGINT UNSIGNED, IN `business_id_param` INT UNSIGNED)
    NO SQL
BEGIN

DECLARE dossier_id INT;
DECLARE query_string VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE cursor_List_isdone BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE user_dossiers CURSOR FOR
Select ld.id, lwp.query_string
FROM lending_users_dossiers ld 
JOIN lending_where_to_pays lwp ON ld.lending_where_to_pay_id = lwp.id
WHERE user_id = user_id_param
  AND (ld.status = 'activated' OR ld.status = 'finished');
  # 'finished' is for loans

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET cursor_List_isdone = TRUE;

Open user_dossiers;  

loop_List: LOOP
  FETCH user_dossiers INTO dossier_id, query_string;  
    IF cursor_List_isdone THEN
      LEAVE loop_List;
    END IF;

    SET @qry = CONCAT(
                "SELECT ld.id lending_dossier_id, ld.type, SUM(let.credit) balance
                FROM lending_users_dossiers ld
                JOIN lending_ewallet_transactions let
                ON ld.id = let.lending_dossier_id
                WHERE ld.id = ", dossier_id,
                " AND ", business_id_param, " IN(", query_string, ")",
                "GROUP BY ld.id, ld.type");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    
END LOOP loop_List;

Close user_dossiers;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `true`

```
'options' => [
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
]
```

> PDO will emulate prepared statements/bound parameters for drivers that
> do not natively support them

The second error could be from `fetchAll()`

```
$queryResult = DB::select('call lending_ewallets_balance_in_merchant(?, ?)', [$userId, $businessId]);
```